# Nginx Redirect if GET request only

Tags: php, nginx, http-redirect, nginx-config

I have a redirect (add trailing slash if there's not one) in nginx that I only want to run on GET requests in order to maintain POSTed data. Checking the [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article it seems like this setup is OK?:

```
location / {
  if ($request_method = GET) {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

However this rule appears to get me a 404 error on every request, before actually loading the content (because my 404 handler also goes through index.php I guess?). This is a [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.com) site.

This doesn't seem to be an issue with the redirection part, this works fine (if I have no slash it redirects) it's when a trailing slash is hit that the 404 happens, so I presume it's something with the `try_files` part that's wrong somehow? However, weirdly, if I comment out the whole if statement (so it just runs the try_files) I ***don't*** get the 404.

If it helps here are the rest of the location blocks etc. in the config (these all follow the `location /` block shown above)

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~* \.(css|js|gif|png|ico|svg)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$uri&$args;
    expires 7d;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg)$ {
    expires 7d;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `if` context processes all of the GET requests.

Assuming that the POST requests should be handled by `/index.php`, you could use the `if` block to handle all POST requests instead.

For example:

```
location / {
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Applied to my config and it works great. Marked as accepted.